# Unexpected fault address

Tags: go-ethereum, error, aws

I picked up an Ethereum Blockchain at AWS ECS almost 3 months ago, it was working perfectly until I got this bug yesterday from the mining node:

```
unexpected fault address 0x7fb93c71d000
[signal SIGBUS: bus error code=0x2 addr=0x7fb99641a000 pc=0x4733c0]
goroutine 273542628 [running]
runtime.throw(0xf75488, 0x5)
```

I managed to get the mineral back and have it replicated from the client, but it turns out that it has happened again and it has even happened to me already in the client. This address is not linked to any wallet or hash of transaction or anything processed by the Blockchain. What could be the cause of this error and how to avoid it?
Using Geth/v1.8.2-stable/linux-amd64/go1.9.7

Comment: SIGBUS signal on Linux is quite generic. It might be a hardware error or that the system is running out of memory.

Comment: The node drop coincides with a high peak in CPU consumption, each node is running on EC2 instances of AWS, they have 4Gb of RAM reserved and can consume up to 8Gb before AWS ECS kills them by high consumption, the RAM consumption has never reached 100% but the CPU does, almost up to 200% usage reports AWS

Comment: If you are running a PoW blockchain I'd suggest to switch to a PoA or to use less threads for mining than available cores in your system.

Answer (score 0):

I have to clear space in root directory to resolve this